# How to track emails sent by row value in google sheets using google analytics?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I'm sending emails to a bunch of people using a script that takes emails from the column E. I'd like to track the emails, whether they're opened or not and bounce rate.
I've inserted a pixel by the sender's name in the email body that is in a cell in google sheets. The same pixel is used in the GA tracking link:

```html
Sender name
<img src ="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1&cid=CLIENT_ID_NUMBER&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=recipient_id&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=TEST_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN&dp=%2Femail%2Fnewsletter1&dt=My%20Newsletter">
```

I've inserted this code snippet into an html file and opened the file on browser. After that, I've used the text from browser in the email body in the google sheets. When I use the same text from browser in email body sent directly from my gmail, it gets data into google analytics in real-time events. But when inserted into the mailbody, it isn't showing. The copied text is basically a pixel inserted.

This is supposed to be getting data into Google analytics.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output / tracebacks). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @THess I'm uploading the code I already have.

Comment: @THess just updated with the code body

Comment: How do you get the analytics data? How are you sending the email? Can you provide more information for the entire process?

Comment: @Kessy sure. Updated above.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for the email, since the error is on the mailbody?